# Java EE 8 application failed to start on Wildfly 25 after adding Extension

Tags: java, wildfly, java-ee-8

I am faced with a strange issue trying to create a custom Scope in my application.

I made minimal sample application to illustrate the problem.

Environment:

- Java 11 (but same with 17 either)
- Wildfly 25.0.0.Final

*build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.example.extension'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11

war {
    archiveName 'extension.war'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'jakarta.platform', name: 'jakarta.jakartaee-api', version: '8.0.0'
}
```

*Main.java*

```
package com.example.extension;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class Main {

    @Inject
    SampleClass sc;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sc.sayHello();
    }
}
```

*SampleClass.java*

```
package com.example.extension;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SampleClass {
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

At that stage everything is ok:

> INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) Hello world

But after adding a new empty class to the project

*SampleExtension.java*

```
package com.example.extension;

import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension;

public class SampleExtension implements Extension { }
```

It starts to fail:

> com.example.extension : extension.war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit."extension.war".component.Main.WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type SampleClass with qualifiers @Default
> at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject com.example.extension.Main.sc
> at com.example.extension.Main.sc(Main.java:0)
> "}}
> com.example.extension : extension.war: Artifact is deployed successfully

I'm new in the Java EE world and I stuck with it. Please explain what is wrong with my code?

P.S. I've checked the same code using Jakarta EE 9.1 and GlassFish 6.2.2 (have to change imports from `javax` to `jakarta`) and there is no such issue.

Comment: Do you have a `beans.xml` in your WAR?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins No, I have no beans.xml

Comment: It seems to me that issue is tied with a fact that I introduce EJB (@Singleton
@Startup) bean in my app to support eager initialization

Comment: If you want to use a CDI extension you need to provide, even if it's empty, a `beans.xml` file.

Comment: I don't know what the specification says about it but may be if you create an `Extension` class then the file `/META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension` becomes mandatory. Try creating it (with your FQCN inside). Have tried with a previous version of Wildfly? Or with another Java EE 8 certified server?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Post your comment as an answer, please. It's works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're adding a CDI extension you need to include a `beans.xml` in your deployment. Per the [specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#bean_archive):

> An archive which:
>
> - contains a beans.xml file with the bean-discovery-mode of none, or,
> - contains an extension and no beans.xml file
>
> is not a bean archive.